# SoapException when calling method of service

Tags: c#, web-services

I've generated the proxy clients of a webservice using the wsdl.
When I try to call a method of this service like this:

```
var service = Wse3ServiceProxyFactory.Create<MyExample_IMyExampleHttpService();
var result = service.getAllAdresses();
```

I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred in System.Web.Services.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The [action] cannot be processed at the receiver.

Unfortunately this message tells me nothing and I have no clue where to look for the error.

Has anyone had this error and knows what I have to look for?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want to debug the program and see the exception. Remember to always look at the nested inner exceptions, sometimes the real details are in there.

Comment: What web service technology are you using? Anything more you can tell about the service?

Comment: @Jeffrey Wieder: I tried to debug and step into the method but it fails with "unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine failed. Invalid access to memory location"

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: The web service technology is SOAP. What exactly do you want to know about the service? It's the first time using it so I don't really know what infos to provide :)

Comment: Can you debug on your development machine?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. the web service isn't from us, we're just the consumers